# custom MFT with windows universal app

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, ms-media-foundation

I created a Custom MFT for my windows universal app. The purpose of it, is to retrieve NV12 frames.

In the windows phone part everything is working great. I'm calling:

`await this._mediaCaptureManager.AddEffectAsync(MediaStreamType.VideoPreview, "CustomMFT.AddPipeline", propertySet);`

but in the same line I have a exception for Windows 8.1 app, saying :

`A first chance exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in mscorlib.dll
WinRT information: The data specified for the media type is invalid, inconsistent, or not supported by this object.
Additional information: The data specified for the media type is invalid, inconsistent, or not supported by this object.
The data specified for the media type is invalid, inconsistent, or not supported by this object.`

I registered this component in the package manifest like I did for the windows phone project.
So what am I doing wrong ? Any ideas of how to solve this ?

Comment: What is your desktop camera's output type? How do you initialize MediaCapture object?

Comment: The camera is the back camera of the surface pro 3. If I comment this line: "_mediaCaptureManager.AddEff" the preview of the Camera is working.
`this._mediaCaptureManager = new MediaCapture();

                MediaCaptureInitializationSettings settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings();
                DeviceInformation chosenDeviceInformation;
...
                    await this._mediaCaptureManager.InitializeAsync(settings);
_mediaCaptureManager.SetPreviewRotation(VideoRotation.Clockwise90Degrees);
                capturePreview.Source = _mediaCaptureManager;

...`

Comment: Could you try using the [SetMediaStreamPropertiesAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700895.aspx) to set the desired media type before starting preview and adding the MFT? Surface has USB camera, while phone has MIPI, and default media types are different. [MFTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff685116(v=vs.85).aspx) may help you to determine the source of the problem in this case.

Comment: You're right, I used SetMediaStreamProperties and it worked. Thanks for you help!